# How to edit the median line and add an average to seaborn.boxenplot() using subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using the [seaborn boxenplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html) / [letter-value plot](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/letter-value-plot.html) inside two subplots like this

```
data = np.random.randn(100, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), ncols=1, nrows=2,
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[len(mat_cat), 1]})
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.boxenplot(data=data[:][:4], ax=ax[0], orient='h')
sns.boxenplot(data=data[:][5], ax=ax[1], orient='h')
ax[0].set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax[1].set_xlim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

Now I would like to <strike>edit the appearance of the median dash (e.g. a red line instead of black) and also</strike> add the mean (e.g. as a dashed blue line) inside the plots.

However I cannot figure out how to do that. For instance, when I do something like `ax[0].plot()` the boxes get plotted on top of each other. Any ideas?

---

## Update

I figured out how to edit the existing median. If I add the following code the median dash of the upper sub-plot will become dashed, red, and 20% transparent.

```
for l in ax[0].lines:
    l.set_linestyle('--')
    l.set_color('r')
    l.set_alpha(0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I partly solved the problem. **Nevertheless, this is rather a workaround than an answer and I would still prefer to have a better one.** For instance that allows me to have dashes instead of a point for the means.

In order to fix the median, I use the following:

```
for l in ax[0].lines:
    l.set_linestyle('--')
    l.set_color('r')
    l.set_alpha(0.8)
```

For adding the means, I (ab-)use [`sns.swarmplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot) along with the `ax` keyword:

```
sns.swarmplot(x=[m.mean() for m in data[:][:4]], y=np.arange(len(data[:][:4])), 
              color='0.3', edgecolor='0.3', linewidth=3,
              ax=ax[0], orient='h')
```

So the total code looks like this:

```
data = np.random.randn(100, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), ncols=1, nrows=2, 
                       gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[len(mat_cat), 1]})
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.boxenplot(data=data[:][:4], ax=ax[0],
             orient='h')
sns.swarmplot(x=[m.mean() for m in data[:][:4]], y=np.arange(len(data[:][:4])), color='0.3', edgecolor='0.3', linewidth=3,
              ax=ax[0], orient='h')
for l in ax[0].lines:
    l.set_linestyle('--')
    l.set_color('r')
    l.set_alpha(0.8)    
sns.boxenplot(data=data[:][5], ax=ax[1], orient='h')
for l in ax[1].lines:
    l.set_linestyle('--')
    l.set_color('r')
    l.set_alpha(0.8)    
sns.swarmplot(x=data[:][5].mean(), y=np.arange(1), 
              color='0.3', edgecolor='0.3', linewidth=3,
              ax=ax[1], orient='h')
ax[0].set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax[1].set_xlim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: For the mean just something like `ax[0].plot(data[:4].mean(axis=0), range(5), 'ko')` is simpler. For the median I don't think you can do any better. A proper solution would require changes to the signature.